# Internal resistance of signal source

Tags: amplifier, signal, resistance, oscilloscope

It was told me that a signal sent to the circuit can be rapresented by \$V_{sig}\$ and \$R_{sig}\$, where \$R_{sig}\$ is the internal resistance of signal source.

Now, let's consider that we have a waveform generator and we connect it to an oscilloscope. Then, we send the oscilloscope signal to our circuit where there is a BJT that we want to use an an amplifier.

I think that the signal source is the oscilloscope because I sent the signal to the circuit after I have set the signal amplitude thanks to the oscilloscope..

So the internal resistance of signal source should be the internal resistance of the oscilloscope.. or is it given by "internal resistance of the oscilloscope" + "internal resistance of the waveform generator"? Or am I on the wrong way and it is given by the internal resistance of the waveform generator?

[image]

Comment: Oscilloscopes don't generally have outputs, unless they include a signal generator.  Could you please provide a drawing of how you want to connect this?  That would make things clearer for us as well as for you.

Comment: I think your bjt and your oscilloscope inputs are wired in parallel, thus the \$R_{sig}\$ is the waveform generator's.

Comment: @JRE updated question!

Comment: @VladimirCravero could you explain me why?

Comment: An oscilloscope (ideally) doesn't cause any load on the source.  Practically, they have a very high input impedance (around 1 million ohms) and a very low capacitance (some few picofarads) so that they do present a load to the generator, but a very tiny one.

Comment: Hmm you have a fundamental misunderstanding about what the 'scope is doing.  You've got a Tee on chan1. one of the scope.  If you pull off the Tee (from the scope.) the output won't change.  You could also move the Tee so that it was either on the output of the generator or the input to your board and still nothing would change.

Comment: @GeorgeHerold but if I set a different amplitude for the input, I obtain a different value for the amplitude output.. do you agree?

Comment: @GeorgeHerold I'm going to think about it... meanwhile thanks for your help! (unfortunately I haven't the oscilloscope and the generator near to me and I have to recall the equipment...)

Comment: @GeorgeHerold Thanks to your help, the matter is clearer for me... I need a little help again.. When I look at the input, I don't see v_sig, but the voltage (v_i) after the internal resistence of the generator... is it correct? (http://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/~Matthew.James/engn2211-2002/notes/bjtimg72.gif)

Comment: @GeorgeHerold \$V_{in}= V_{sig}- I_{in}R_{sig}\$

Comment: Excellent!  carry on then.  (I'm deleting my comments.)

Comment: @GeorgeHerold I'm sorry.. I haven't understood " carry on then".. what do I have to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three impedances involved, and all three are in parallel.  The impedance of the oscilloscope will be so high that we can ignore it - an extremely high impedance in parallel to a lower impedance doesn't change the total impedance enough to notice.

That leaves the impedance of the signal generator and the amplifier.  Rsig is simply the output impedance of the signal generator. This is the impedance feeding your amplifier.  Ideally, you would want the impedance of the amplifier to be the same.

Comment: Ok, I have understood :) But I have another question... If the signal doesn't go into the oscilloscope, I set the wave amplitude only for analyzing the BJT response.. it hasn't a real effect to the circuit.. Is it right? But I have noticed that increasing the wave amplitude, the signal saturates. Is it due to an uncorrect dc bias point? thanks for your help

Comment: For my opinion, a bias point cannot be "incorrect" - either it suits your needs or not. On the other hand - of course, each signal can drive a BJT into saturation. The bias point has an optimal value if the signal reaches saturation limits on both extremes (pos. and neg.) approximately at the same amplitude values.

Comment: @LvW it was told me that if a dc bias point is "good", the output can be "free" to swing.. so I have thought that if the output is cut, it isn't a good dc bias point... Is it wrong?

Comment: @sunrise, no - in principle your understanding ("free" to be swing) is not false, however, the output always will be limited ("cut") at a certain level. And this is not an indication for an "incorrect" bias point. That´s what I wanted to point out.

Comment: @LvW Ok, I have understood. Many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

The parallel resistance of both the source and the oscilloscope.

You have connected them in parallel, so the combined resistance is \$\frac{R_1R_2}{R_1+R_2}\$. The oscilloscope is a small capacitor, so its DC resistance goes toward infinity, and the total source resistance is given by the generator.

Obviously, that is for the static case only. If you generate a variable signal, your total resistance calculation becomes a lot more complex, and needs to include signal reflection, the wave impedance of the cables used etc.

This is where expensive oscilloscope probes come in -- these are optimized to generate as little change in the electrical properties of the device under test as possible. The closest you can get with a cable based solution is a T connector on the oscilloscope frontend, so the two points of impedance mismatch (cable split and oscilloscope input amplifier) are as close together as possible.

Comment: Mmmh... I haven't understood... Why source and oscilloscope are connected in parallel? I send the oscilloscope signal in the oscilloscope..

Comment: Yes, but you also have the input to your amplifier connected to the same lines as the signal generator and the oscilloscope.  Strictly speaking, all three are in parallel.

Comment: @JRE I thought that the signal was really generated after the setting of the wave amplitude... (Is it wrong?) and so, I thought, oscilloscope and wf generator couldn't be in parallel.. they could be in a kind of series..

Comment: They are in parallel.  The signal from the generator goes into the oscilloscope and the amplifier at the same time.  The signal from the generator does NOT go into the oscillopscope and then back out  to the amplifier - the signal doesn NOT go THROUGH the oscilloscope.